# Gerrit push the same changesets to both master and a branch

Tags: git, gerrit

Working on a feature branch in Gerrit, I want to push my feature branch changes to *master* (so others can make use of it) as well as to my *feature* branch (so I can keep working on it without the changes on master), but once I've pushed to one, I can't gerrit push to the other.

For example, if I `git push HEAD:refs/for/master` then a subsequent `git push HEAD:refs/for/feature` will result in:

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
To ssh://gerrit.server/repo.git
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/feature (no new changes)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://gerrit.server/repo.git'
```

Of course there are new changes, but only with respect to a different branch.

At the moment, I have two options:

1. Push to the feature branch, get it tested, reviewed & submitted, then manually merge it into master and get that tested, reviewed & submitted.

   - The problem here is that if other changes are merged into master between my pulling master to do the merge and my merge commit being submitted, then we end up with an extra unnecessary merge.
2. Push to master, get it tested, reviewed & submitted, then get our gerrit guru to update the feature branch ref in gerrit to the where it needs to be.

   - Apart from being a hack, with the potential to go badly wrong, it isn't something you would want to have to ask someone to do very often.
   - The CI server only runs tests on *master*, not on the branch.

Neither of these solutions is very satisfactory.

Ideally I would like to just push to the *feature* branch, and then push to *master* and have gerrit realise that the second push was to get the commit (or commits) merged to master; or alternatively, push to master then push to the feature branch, and have gerrit realise that this is just a request to fast-forward the feature branch ref. Unfortunately I haven't found any way to do this.

Is there a clean way to push a change, or set of changes, to both their feature branch and master?

---

Note, we have merge based workflow rather than a rebase based workflow, so answers which rely on a rebase workflow will not be useful to us.

Having discovered [Selecting Merge Base](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-upload.html#base) I thought the `base` option might be what I was looking for, however when I try `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master` followed by `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/feature%base=$(git rev-parse origin/feature)` the push to the feature branch fails in the same way as if I'd just done `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/feature` i.e. it says `[remote rejected]` due to `(no new changes)`.

---

We have also tried enabling the `create-new-change-for-all-not-in-target` option in the Gerrit project configuration, but it fails in exactly the same way:

```
$git commit -am "New commit for feature and master."
[fix 1234567] New Commit
 19 files changed, 19 insertions(+), 19 deletions(-)

$git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
Counting objects: 48, done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (25/25), done.
Writing objects: 100% (25/25), 2.20 KiB, done.
Total 25 (delta 24), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (24/24)
remote: Processing changes: new: 1, refs: 1, done    
remote: 
remote: New Changes:
remote:   http://gerrit.server/1234 New commit for feature and master.
remote: 
To ssh://gerrit.server/repo.git
 * [new branch]      HEAD -> refs/for/master

$git push origin HEAD:refs/for/feature
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
To ssh://gerrit.server/repo.git
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/feature (no new changes)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://gerrit.server/repo.git'
```

I also tried pushing to the feature branch first and then mastedr, but as expected, this results in the same rejection.

Comment: Have you tried this: push to the first branch then checkout the second one, merge the first branch into it and then push. I assume the problem is that you are trying to push to a different branch than the current name. example: working on featureX and pushing to master

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to Gerrit, we use slightly different approach. We do not maintain a *topic branches* but we use *change subjects* provided by Gerrit. That is, instead of `git push HEAD:refs/for/feature` you can submit your changes concerning one *topic* with `git push HEAD:refs/for/master/feature`. Gerrit treats it as *this is a commit with "feature" and it will be eventually merged to the master*. You can have multiple changes with the same topic (they should probably be mapped to classic, local feature branch on your dev machine). Gerrit even provides nice filtering features by change topics.

Then, as `master` updates you can rebase your whole topic to the it and continue to develop the feature with code from `master`. When the feature is ready, it can be merged to the master.

Such workflow enables you to test your new feature during work/review phase with the newest changes from master.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts fracz, but I don't really want to go through the hassle of trying to get our team to change workflow. It was difficult enough to get us to use the current workflow. I find it is always a bad idea to let your workflow be whatever is easiest for the tools you have, rather than adapting and fixing your tools so that they fit your workflow - hence looking for a solution which doesn't require a chance to our workflow.

Comment: Then, IMO your problem is not caused by Gerrit. If you want to update topic branch with master you have to either merge with it or rebase to it and then `push -f` the changes to the remote as  G. Sylvie Davies suggests.

Comment: It is a gerrit problem though. If we weren't using gerrit, I could happily push the same to the branch and to master without issue (no need to force push, which we would reject anyway). The problem with gerrit is that if I gerrit push to the branch and then gerrit push the same change to master, it rejects the gerrit push to master as the commit has already been pushed to the branch (both have the same Change-ID, so gerrit sees them as the same change).

Answer (score 1):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37392667/1127485) to [Gerrit with tracked feature branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37390823/1127485): Enabling the `create-new-change-for-all-not-in-target` option in Gerrit >= 2.11 to [take into account target branch when determining new changes to open](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.11/project-configuration.html#_use_target_branch_when_determining_new_changes_to_open) should also help in your case.

Comment: We have just enabled this setting in the Gerrit web Gui for a project and tried doing a feature branch push, but we are still getting `remote rejected` with `no new changes`. Should we be able to just enable it at the project level, or do we need to enable it anywhere else too?

Comment: It should work by only enabling it at the project level. However, it will only for work changes that have been pushed after the option was enabled. I.e. if you already pushed the original change before, enabling this option will not make pushing the same change to a different branch work. Also the original change needs to be pushed after this option has been enabled.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my question with details of what happened when I tried what you suggested. Thanks.