# Gerrit with tracked feature branches?

Tags: git, gerrit

We (git/gerrit newbs) are trying to use gerrit with feature branches. The workflow we are trying to implement is as follows:

1. User creates a feature branch, pushes it to the remote repo directly (no review) with `git push -u origin users-branch`.
2. As changes pile up in the master branch, user does `git pull --rebase origin master` (`--rebase` is needed because otherwise git creates a merge commit, and merge commits cannot be pushed through gerrit).
3. User continues to push his changes to the remote repo with `git push --force origin users-branch` (`--force` is needed because of `--rebase` at the previous stage; I'm looking for a better way to do this).
4. Other users can contribute to the feature branch by pushing their own changes.
5. When the feature is ready, the user pushes it for review with `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master`.

The last step doesn't work because commits that were pushed to gerrit at any stage cannot be pushed again.

The gerrit manual suggests to amend the commits you want to push again. This seems complicated and error prone.

It all works if user never pushes his changes to remote repo, because gerrit doesn't see the changes until they are pushed for review. But this is exactly what we don't like.

It seems possible to use a different repo for feature branches, such that gerrit never sees duplicate change IDs, but this again seems like a needless complication.

Is there a way to do what we want safely and elegantly?

Comment: *merge commits cannot be pushed through gerrit* you can reconfigure this though. But maybe you don't want that, which I would understand

Comment: What is the point of using gerrit if you don't want (most) commits to be reviewed? I think that is one of its greatest strengths, don't allow anyone to push anything unless it's been reviewed

Comment: @TimCastelijns I want all commits to the master and release branches to be reviewed, but not for the feature branches.

Comment: but feature-braches are designed to make development process predictable. it's better to detect and fix all possible mistakes and design flaws as early as possible, until someone created other mistakes on top of these ones.

Comment: @user3159253 Changes are reviewed when pushed to the master branch. That's the mode of work throughout the organization. We're not going to review them twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running at least [Gerrit 2.11](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/ReleaseNotes/ReleaseNotes-2.11.html#_configuration) you can benefit from the [fix](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/#/c/59909/) for [issue 1195](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=1195) and enable the `create-new-change-for-all-not-in-target` option to [take into account target branch when determining new changes to open](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.11/project-configuration.html#_use_target_branch_when_determining_new_changes_to_open).

Comment: Thank you, this could be it. However this option is grayed out in the project settings (all options in fact are). Disabled by admins?

Comment: That sounds as if none of the groups you're in has "Owner" permissions for the project.

Comment: Yeah, apparently I have full permissions for the git repo but not for the gerrit project that sits on top of it. Asked the admin to change it, will report as soon as I have a chance to test it.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to work on Gerrit with a pull-request workflow (Like Github, Bitbucket, ...).

We just created a Gerrit client tool to do that:

https://github.com/Cosium/vet

With `vet`, you can have feature branches and you can add any number of commits without amending or rebasing the feature branch.