# Can Gerrit be configured to allow you to push the same change to multiple branches?

Tags: git, gerrit

I often find that when I want to fix a bug which spans multiple releases, I have to jump through hoops to get the fix propagated.

What I have to do at the moment is:

- Fix the bug on the hotfix branch for the release where it was introduced.
- Gerrit push the fix to that hotfix branch.
- Wait for it to be reviewed before submitting (and thus getting merged in by Gerrit).
- For each subsequent release, go to it's hotfix branch and perform a manual merge of the fix.
- Gerrit push each of these merge commits to their hot fix branches.
- Wait for all of these gerrit reviews to be completed before submitting (hoping that the head of the branch hasn't changed, forcing yet another merge commit).

Since I don't want to use cherry pick<sup>†</sup> and we don't use a rebase workflow, what I would like to do is:

- Fix the bug on the hotfix branch for the release where it was introduced.
- Gerrit push the fix to that hotfix branch and all subsequent releases hot fix branches.
- Wait for all reviews to complete before submitting (letting Gerrit do the merge at the current head of the branch).

The problem is, this doesn't work. After I've pushed the fix to the first branch, any attempt to push it to any other branch fails because that change isn't 'new'. It may be new to the branches I want it on, but it isn't new to gerrit as a whole.

My reason for wanting to do this is so that I can a) avoid all of the manual merge steps, and b) avoid the possibility that additional unnecessary merges which might happen when those manual merges are submitted. Essentially I want gerrit to do it's own merge on submit, just as it does for the push to the first branch.

So, are there any ways to achieve the work flow I want? Is there any way to configured Gerrit to allow you to push the same change to multiple branches?

<sup>† No arguments, I won't be persuaded, I'm not using cherry pick or rebase for this, both are just lying about your history.</sup>

<sup>Note this question is similar to, but a more generalised version of my question [Gerrit push the same changesets to both master and a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36017671/42473) so hopefully an answer here will answer that question too.</sup>

---

Having discovered [Selecting Merge Base](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-upload.html#base) I thought the `base` option might be what I was looking for, however when I try `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master` followed by `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/release-hotfix%base=$(git rev-parse origin/release-hotfix)` the push to the hotfix branch fails in the same way as if I'd just done `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/release-hotfix` i.e. it says `[remote rejected]` due to `(no new changes)`.

I have also tried enabling the `create-new-change-for-all-not-in-target` option in the project, but it continues to reject pushes with 'no new changes'.

Comment: "No arguments, I won't be persuaded, I'm not using cherry pick for this." Why?

Comment: Because cherry pick is evil, it's religious war territory (like lying about your history by using rebase) and I'm not getting into it here @mkasberg.

Comment: "Gerrit push the fix to that hotfix branch and all subsequent releases hot fix branches." That's a complicated/confusing step. It doesn't really work like that. When you do something like `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master`, you're pushing a commit along with all it's ancestors (on a specific branch). What exactly do you mean by "push it to all subsequent release hot fix branches"?

Comment: What I mean is that when you do a gerrit push, you can specify the destination branch that the commit will be pushed to, reviewed against and eventually merged into once suitable reviews have taken place. Although it is mechanically just a git push, it is logically rather different @mkasberg.

Comment: I'm not seeing how this is different from your mentioned other question. Isn't the underlying problem the same, i.e. that Gerrit my default does not regard such changes as new?

Comment: "when you do a gerrit push, you can specify the destination branch that the commit will be pushed to, reviewed against and eventually merged into..." Can you explain how this is different than a cherry-pick?

Comment: Look at the commit graph @mkasberg a cherry pick and a merge are completely different things.

Comment: Thanks @sschuberth as my understanding of my current problem has increased, I think it has got closer to my other question. If one question actually gets an answer which works, I'll suggest the other be closed as a dup of the question with the good answer.

Comment: I understand the difference between a cherry-pick and a merge. I was asking because the steps you listed as "what I would like to do" didn't include using `git merge`. You said, "Gerrit push the fix to that hotfix branch and all subsequent releases hot fix branches," which implies you'd like to do something like `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/branch-a` followed by `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/branch-b`. If you ran those commands, and branch-b was several commits ahead of branch-a, Gerrit would rebase the commit for you. Maybe you could include the commands you've tried so far?

Comment: The merge is implicit in in the gerrit submit @mkasberg if you use a merge workflow (which we do) rather than a rebase workflow. As I said, rebase if evil, because it means you lie about your history, so I am not having this argument. Plus, if you reread the question, you will find that I *have* added the commands I used (or rather the equivalent `git` command line commands, we usually only use the command line for things we can't do from egit).